# c# Linq to XML to Object not working in XAMARIN (ios)

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, linq-to-xml

i have a problem to get an xml result from a webservice into a custom class in xamarin (ios).

I've calling a Webservice and get the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ArrayOfCO_App_Table_CO_VERTRETERFTPLOGIN xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<CO_App_Table_CO_VERTRETERFTPLOGIN>
    <id>2</id> 
    <PERSONAL>max.mustermann</PERSONAL> 
    <FTP>127.0.0.1</FTP> 
    <USERNAME /> 
    <PASSWORD /> 
    <DIRECTORY /> 
    <ACTIVE>1</ACTIVE> 
    <USERDOMAIN /> 
    <ZIPFILENAME>bla.zip</ZIPFILENAME> 
    <DBFILENAME>bla.db</DBFILENAME> 
</CO_App_Table_CO_VERTRETERFTPLOGIN>
</ArrayOfCO_App_Table_CO_VERTRETERFTPLOGIN>
```

I want to insert it into a class.

```
  public class co_vertreterftplogin
 {
public string id { get; set; }
public string INVERT { get; set; }
public string PERSONAL { get; set; }
public string FTP { get; set; }
public string USERNAME { get; set; }
public string PASSWORD { get; set; }
public string DIRECTORY { get; set; }
public string ACTIVE { get; set; }
public string USERDOMAIN { get; set; }
public string ZIPFILENAME { get; set; }
public string DBFILENAME { get; set; }
}
```

My Code:

```
var xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(result);
XElement dx = xmldoc.Elements().FirstOrDefault();

var data = (from item in dx.Elements().FirstOrDefault().Descendants()
select new Database.Tabellen.co_vertreterftplogin
{
        id =item.Element("id").Value,
        PERSONAL="",
        FTP="",
        USERNAME="",
        PASSWORD="",
        DIRECTORY="",
        ACTIVE="",
        USERDOMAIN="",
        ZIPFILENAME="",
        DBFILENAME=""

});

Database.Tabellen.co_vertreterftplogin bla = data.First ();
```

My problem is that the data.First() is allways null. Or in other words, "my code is not working" :-)

Thx forward

Comment: It's hard to know what you're doing wrong without knowing what problem you're seeing. (There's the fact that you're looking for an `id` element without specifying the namespace, for a start... but that may not be everything.)

Comment: ahh. sorry. Too much hours on programming :-)

The error is that the the data.first(); is null

thx

Comment: No, `First()` will never return `null` when you're selecting something non-null. I don't think that's what you're actually seeing.

Comment: I will get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
on line 
Database.Tabellen.co_vertreterftplogin bla = data.First ();

Comment: Right, that's not the same as `First()` returning null. That's because `item.Element("id")` is returning null, because you haven't specified the namespace... Please edit your question to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here. Firstly, I believe you've got too many calls to `Elements`/`Descendants` so you're actually iterating over all the *descendants* of `<CO_App_Table_CO_VERTRETERFTPLOGIN>`. Next, you haven't specified the namespace when you fetch the `id` element. Due to this attribute in the root element:

```
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"
```

all the rest of the elements are in that namespace. So you want:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(result);
var data = doc.Root       // ArrayOfCO_App_Table_CO_VERTRETERFTPLOGIN
              .Elements() // CO_App_Table_CO_VERTRETERFTPLOGIN
              .Select(x => new Database.Tabellen.co_vertreterftplogin
              {
                  id = (string) x.Element(ns + "id"),
                  ...
              });
```

I would also *strongly* advise you to revisit the naming of both your type and properties to follow .NET naming conventions.

Comment: Hi,thanks for helping me. It is working now. The many calls are a mix of many testing results and inexperience of LinqToXml. The namespace thing was the main reason that my code was not working.

I promise to revisit the naming convention. thx